# Issue rendering video on image using sceneform

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore, sceneform

I am successfully able to render video on the image when it detect the image. Problem is when I remove the image from that place video still keep showing on that place whereas the image does not exist anymore on that place. 
Below is my code when i used to create `ARScene`.

```
  private fun createArScene() {
    // Create an ExternalTexture for displaying the contents of the video.
    externalTexture = ExternalTexture().also {
        mediaPlayer.setSurface(it.surface)
    }

    // Create a renderable with a material that has a parameter of type 'samplerExternal' so that
    // it can display an ExternalTexture.
    ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(requireContext(), R.raw.augmented_video_model)
        .build()
        .thenAccept { renderable ->
            videoRenderable = renderable
            renderable.isShadowCaster = false
            renderable.isShadowReceiver = false
            renderable.material.setExternalTexture("videoTexture", externalTexture)
        }
        .exceptionally { throwable ->
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create ModelRenderable", throwable)
            return@exceptionally null
        }

    videoAnchorNode = VideoAnchorNode().apply {
        setParent(arSceneView.scene)
    }
  }
```

on update listener

```
    override fun onUpdate(frameTime: FrameTime) {


    val frame = arSceneView.arFrame


    if (frame == null || frame.camera.trackingState != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
        return
    }

    val updatedAugmentedImages = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage::class.java)
    for (augmentedImage in updatedAugmentedImages) {
        if (activeAugmentedImage != augmentedImage && augmentedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
            try {
                dismissArVideo()
                playbackArVideo(augmentedImage)
                break
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not play video [${augmentedImage.name}]", e)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**So what I believe I need to keep checking externalTexture object but the problem is how my system will know that I am not focusing on the image anymore. so that I can kill it** ?

Answer (score 0):

On update listener you can track the image like below,

```
Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
    Collection<AugmentedImage> augmentedImages = 
frame.getUpdatedTrackables((AugmentedImage.class));
    for (AugmentedImage image: augmentedImages){
        if(image.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING){
            if(image.getName().equals("image")){

                isImageDetected = true;

                playVideo(image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose()), 
image.getExtentX(), image.getExtentZ());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can check with tracking states like STOPPED, PAUSED and TACKING

Comment: I have added my on update listener in the code. Can you see its different then what you have provided ?

Comment: The problem is it detect when I change image1.jpg to image2.jpg , but if i remove image1.jpg on that place it keep showing the video which was mapped to image1.jpg , My problem is how to detect that there is no image after scanning image1.jpg and stop the video

Comment: Please have a look on this https://medium.com/krootl/arcore-sceneform-video-crop-n-fade-in-1c70d72efaf

Comment: @VishvenduPalawat Did u get any solution?

Comment: No , my use case is different that what they have showed there

Comment: @VishvenduPalawat What is your use case?